# where clause not working in spark sql dataframe

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I've created a dataframe which contains 3 columns : zip, lat, lng

I want to select the lat and lng values where zip = 00650

So, I tried using :

```
sqlContext.sql("select lat,lng from census where zip=00650").show()
```

But it is returning ArrayOutOfBound Exception because it does not have any values in it. 
If I remove the where clause it is running fine.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong ?

### Update:

dataframe schema:

```
root 
|-- zip: string (nullable = true) 
|-- lat: string (nullable = true) 
|-- lng: string (nullable = true)
```

First 10 rows are :

```
+-----+---------+-----------+
|  zip|      lat|        lng|
+-----+---------+-----------+
|00601|18.180555| -66.749961|
|00602|18.361945| -67.175597|
|00603|18.455183| -67.119887|
|00606|18.158345| -66.932911|
|00610|18.295366| -67.125135|
|00612|18.402253| -66.711397|
|00616|18.420412| -66.671979|
|00617|18.445147| -66.559696|
|00622|17.991245| -67.153993|
|00623|18.083361| -67.153897|
|00624|18.064919| -66.716683|
|00627|18.412600| -66.863926|
|00631|18.190607| -66.832041|
|00637|18.076713| -66.947389|
|00638|18.295913| -66.515588|
|00641|18.263085| -66.712985|
|00646|18.433150| -66.285875| 
|00647|17.963613| -66.947127|
|00650|18.349416| -66.578079|
```

Comment: can you show what is the schema of your dataframe using `dataFrame.printSchema()`

Comment: `root
 |-- zip: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lng: string (nullable = true)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in your schema `zip` is of type `String`, so your query should be something like this

```
sqlContext.sql("select lat, lng from census where zip = '00650'").show()
```

### Update:

If you are using `Spark 2` then you can do this:

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val dataFrame = Seq(("10.023", "75.0125", "00650"),("12.0246", "76.4586", "00650"), ("10.023", "75.0125", "00651")).toDF("lat","lng", "zip")

dataFrame.printSchema()

dataFrame.select("*").where(dataFrame("zip") === "00650").show()

dataFrame.registerTempTable("census")

sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT lat, lng FROM census WHERE zip = '00650'").show()
```

output:

```
root
 |-- lat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lng: string (nullable = true)
 |-- zip: string (nullable = true)

+-------+-------+-----+
|    lat|    lng|  zip|
+-------+-------+-----+
| 10.023|75.0125|00650|
|12.0246|76.4586|00650|
+-------+-------+-----+

+-------+-------+
|    lat|    lng|
+-------+-------+
| 10.023|75.0125|
|12.0246|76.4586|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it also but still it is returning nothing

Comment: Same error with the updated version also - ArrayIndexOutOfBound. I think the problem is with the data but the rows are like : `00650,18.349416, -66.578079` which I don't think is wrong.

Comment: @Ishan can you just print the dataframe 10 rows and show it.

Comment: did you try this `dataFrame.select("*").where(dataFrame("zip") === "00650").show()` ??

Comment: if you are running this using `spark-shell` then you can use `dataFrame.where($"zip" === "00650").show()`

Comment: @PrasadKhode yes I've tried your answer. But it is not working. And I am using datastax spark.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue using RDD rather that DataFrame. It provided me desired results :

```
val data = sc.textFile("/home/ishan/Desktop/c").map(_.split(","))
val arr=data.filter(_.contains("00650")).take(1)
arr.foreach{a => a foreach println}
```